# django-tables2 ignores ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-tables2

I have these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
```

I'm trying to display `Item` model in table with django-tables2, like this:

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "brand", "categories")

    categories = tables.Column(empty_values=())

    def render_categories(self, value):
        return ', '.join([category.name for category in value.all()])
```

It works fine, except the `Table` ignores the `categories` field and
`value` parameter is equals `None`, and I'm getting error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is bug in django-tables2 when using with django 1.7:
https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/211

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "brand", "categories")

    categories = tables.Column()

    def render_categories(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            return ', '.join([category.name for category in value.all()])
        return '-'
```

Comment: I found that `value = None` is a consequence of a bug in django-tables2 (look at my answer above), it ignores `ManyToManyField` in model. So if I'll do what you wrote - I'll always get an `'-'` as result. Solution is to fix the bug in the `django-tables2`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it hasn't been merged in. As a work around you can do a render with a record and iterate the same way.

ie.

```
 def render_categories(self, record):
        if record.category is not None:
            return ', '.join([category.name for category in record.category.all()])
        return '-'
```

Comment: Oops.  You would need a new field to use because it looks like django-tables2 returns based on the field. So just get a new column or something so you get a full record.

Comment: Hi @Craig, welcome to StackOverflow. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29834989/edit) your question to cover your shame. If it's been five minutes it'll be logged as an edit, but it's better to edit than post a correction as a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the cleaner option but this worked for me:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

   @property
   def categories_str(self):
       return ', '.join([category.name for category in value.all()])


class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    categories = tables.Column(accessor='categories_str')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "brand", "categories")
```

Answer (score -1):

Do This:

```
class ItemTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ("uuid", "name", "brand", "categories")

    categories = tables.Column(empty_values=())

    def render_categories(self, record):
        if record.categories.all():
            return ', '.join([category.name for category in record.categories.all()])
        return '-'
```

Note that empty_values=() is important to be written in tables.Column()